# Массив из цифр каждого разряда данного числа

Tags: массивы, java

Подскажите,пожалуйста, как сделать из числа integer массив, элементами которого будут цифры каждого разряда данного числа в Java?

Comment: Намекаю: следует оперировать целочисленным делением и целочисленным же нахождением остатка. Ну-ка!

Answer (score 2):

```
    int a = 1234; //Данное число
    String num = String.valueOf(a);
    int result[] = new int[num.length()]; //Требуемый массив
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) result[i] = num.charAt(i);
```

Comment: @danpetruk: лучше просто

    String.valueOf(a).toCharArray();

Answer (score 0):

Рекурсивное решение, не создающее лишних объектов в куче во время работы:

```
public static int[] toDigitsArray(int num) {
    return toDigitsArray(num, 1);
}

private static int[] toDigitsArray(int num, int n) {
    int[] digits;
    if (num > 10) {
        digits = toDigitsArray(num / 10, n + 1);
    } else {
        digits = new int[n];
    }
    digits[digits.length - n] = num % 10;

    return digits;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Накидал пока решал пример, мб пригодится:

**Extension**

```
fun Int.toDigitArray(): List<Int> = this.toString().toCharArray().map { it.toString().toInt() }
```

Пример:

```
val number = 124876

val result = number.toDigitArray()

println("$result")
```

Результат:

[1, 2, 4, 8, 7, 6]

Comment: В метках вроде нет, что решать на любом языке.